# Fetch data using volley and display in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-volley

This is my first time working with `Google Maps` in android. I was able to create a map displaying `one marker`. That was a good start for me. However, I would like to display `multiple markers`. To do these, I am fetching the locations from the database using `volley`. However, I am experiencing one problem, one that I have experienced before but I managed to have a work around then and now it has surfaced again in my current project i.e I like using `Singletons` in my application to store data as long as the application is in memory. My `singleton` for instance could hold an `array list of objects` and I can get the array list anywhere and any time in any activity/fragment. However, I need to populate the `arraylist` in my `singleton` before `activity/fragment` becomes active and access the `arraylist` of objects in `onCreate/onCreateView` but it seems the `activity/fragment` loads very fast and a reference to the `arraylist of objects` from the `singleton` is always `null`. In my current project:

This is the `singleton class` that handles all the locations

```
public class PointOfInterestLab {
    private ArrayList<PointOfInterest> mPointOfInterests;
    private static PointOfInterestLab sPointOfInterestLab;
    private Context mAppContext;

    private PointOfInterestLab(Context appContext){
        mAppContext = appContext;
        mPointOfInterests = new ArrayList<PointOfInterest>();

    }

    public static PointOfInterestLab get(Context c){
        if(sPointOfInterestLab == null){
            sPointOfInterestLab = new PointOfInterestLab(c.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return sPointOfInterestLab;

    }

    public ArrayList<PointOfInterest> getPointOfInterests(){
        return mPointOfInterests;

    }

    public PointOfInterest getPointOfInterest(int id){
        for(PointOfInterest pointOfInterest: mPointOfInterests){
            if(pointOfInterest.getID() == id){
                return pointOfInterest;
            }
        }

        return null;

    }

    public void addPointOfInterest(PointOfInterest pointOfInterest){
        mPointOfInterests.add(pointOfInterest);
    }

    public void clearPointOfInterests(){
        mPointOfInterests.clear();
    }

    public void deletePointOfInterest(PointOfInterest pointOfInterest){
        mPointOfInterests.remove(pointOfInterest);

    }
}
```

In the fragment that I want to display the locations:

```
public class PointOfInterestMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static final String TAG = PointOfInterestMapFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //get locations from server
        getPOISFromDB();
    }//end method onCreate

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle saveInstanceState){

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poi_map, parent, false);

        //obtain the support fragment and get notified when the map is ready
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        //pass fragment in getMapAsync handler
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return v;
    }//end method onCreateView

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        ArrayList<PointOfInterest> pointOfInterests;
        pointOfInterests = PointOfInterestLab.get(getActivity())
                .getPointOfInterests();
        for(PointOfInterest pointOfInterest : pointOfInterests){
            //add marker and move camera
            /*LatLng location = new LatLng(pointOfInterest.getLocation().getLatitude()
                    , pointOfInterest.getLocation().getLongitude());
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(location)
                    .title(pointOfInterest.getName()));
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));*/
           Log.d(TAG, pointOfInterest.getName());
        }
        /*This is just for debugging, it is returning a null object
        Meaning by the time the array list of the singleton class
       is being populated this has been called I guess*/
        PointOfInterest pointOfInterest = PointOfInterestLab.get(getActivity()).getPointOfInterest(3);

        LatLng location = new LatLng(pointOfInterest.getLocation().getLatitude(),pointOfInterest.getLocation().getLongitude());
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(location)
                .title("location"));
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));

    }
    //Get locations from db
    private  void getPOISFromDB(){
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_poi_list";

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_POI_LIST, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response);

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("pois");
                    PointOfInterestLab.get(getActivity()).clearPointOfInterests();

                    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id = jsonObject.getInt("poi_id");
                        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        String summary = jsonObject.getString("summary");
                        double latitude =  jsonObject.getDouble("latitude");
                        double longitude = jsonObject.getDouble("longitude");
                        Location location = new Location("dummyProvider");
                        location.setLatitude(latitude);
                        location.setLongitude(longitude);

                        PointOfInterest pointOfInterest = new PointOfInterest(id, name, summary
                                , location);
                        PointOfInterestLab.get(getActivity()).addPointOfInterest(pointOfInterest);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server error: " + error.getMessage());

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                SQLiteHandler sqLiteHandler = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());
                User user = sqLiteHandler.getUserDetails();
                params.put("user_id", user.getUserID());
                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

    }//end method getPOISFromDB

}//end class
```

This is the part of the code that I am using to test for now. I am getting error `PointOfInterest.getLocation()' on a null object reference` on line `LatLng location = new LatLng(pointOfInterest.getLocation().getLatitude(),pointOfInterest.getLocation().getLongitude());`

```
 /*This is just for debugging, it is returning a null object
   Meaning by the time the array list of the singleton class
   is being populated this has been called I guess*/

            PointOfInterest pointOfInterest = PointOfInterestLab.get(getActivity()).getPointOfInterest(3);

            LatLng location = new LatLng(pointOfInterest.getLocation().getLatitude(),pointOfInterest.getLocation().getLongitude());
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(location)
                    .title("location"));
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
```

I have also tried calling the database api in the `onCreate` method of the hosting activity but doesn't seem to work

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ......

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedometer);

        Toolbar toolbar  = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        User user = new User();
        user.checkLogin(MainActivity.this);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

        //runnable to get rid of bug
        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        setTitle("Updates");
        //get locations from db
        getPOISFromDB();
    }//end method onCreate

    private class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return new FirstFragment();
                case 1 :
                   eturn new SecondFragment();

                case 2 :
                    return new PointOfInterestMapFragment();

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 3;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_1);
                case 1 :
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_2);
                case 2 :
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_3);

            }
            return null;
        }

    }//end class MyAdapter  

    private  void getPOISFromDB(){
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_poi_list";

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_POI_LIST, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response);

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("pois");
                    PointOfInterestLab.get(AppController.getInstance()).clearPointOfInterests();

                    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id = jsonObject.getInt("poi_id");
                        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        String summary = jsonObject.getString("summary");
                        double latitude =  jsonObject.getDouble("latitude");
                        double longitude = jsonObject.getDouble("longitude");
                        Location location = new Location("dummyProvider");
                        location.setLatitude(latitude);
                        location.setLongitude(longitude);

                        PointOfInterest pointOfInterest = new PointOfInterest(id, name, summary
                                , location);
                        PointOfInterestLab.get(AppController.getInstance()).addPointOfInterest(pointOfInterest);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server error: " + error.getMessage());

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                SQLiteHandler sqLiteHandler = new SQLiteHandler(AppController.getInstance());
                User user = sqLiteHandler.getUserDetails();
                params.put("user_id", user.getUserID());
                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

    }//end method getPOISFromDB
}
```

How do I display the markers in **onMapReady** method i.e populate the singleton before the **onMapReady** method executes?

Comment: You can call the database api call in activity and store it in our singleton class.After that you can start the fragment . Otherwise call the api in fragment and after that initialize the map when data is fetched.

Comment: make one function which create marker on googleMap object. so after getting successful response you can create this function no. of time your object has LatLong

Comment: @Soham in the onCreate method of the activity or?

Comment: Yeap in `onCreate`. @facilitator.

Comment: @Soham I tried that, still getting `PointOfInterest.getLocation()' on a null object reference` in error in the fragment on line `LatLng location = new LatLng(pointOfInterest.getLocation().getLatitude(),pointOfInterest.getLocation().getLongitude());`

Comment: First of all I am not seeing `PointOfInterest` this as singleton class. Secondly can you update your code of the activity. @facilitator.

Comment: @soham `PointOfInterestLab.java`  is the singleton class `PointOfInterst.java` is just a model for objects of type `PointOfInterest` I am using a `MainActivity` hosting 3 fragments, 3 tabs. Pasted method `getPOISFromDB()` in the activity and called it `onCreate` method

Comment: Can you add the some more code here.

Comment: @Soham added in the question section above..hope that helps

Comment: Set your adapter `viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));` after getting the response from the api. You are initializing the adapter before that's why you are getting null pointer exception.

Comment: @soham Thanks!!!!!...works perfect....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @soham, I changed to initialize my adapter after the response from the api. Removed this line of code in `onCreate` in the `MainActivity`

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ......

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        .......
}
```

Placed it in method `getPOISFromDB()`

```
......

@Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response);

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("pois");
                    PointOfInterestLab.get(AppController.getInstance()).clearPointOfInterests();

                    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id = jsonObject.getInt("poi_id");
                        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        String summary = jsonObject.getString("summary");
                        double latitude =  jsonObject.getDouble("latitude");
                        double longitude = jsonObject.getDouble("longitude");
                        Location location = new Location("dummyProvider");
                        location.setLatitude(latitude);
                        location.setLongitude(longitude);

                        PointOfInterest pointOfInterest = new PointOfInterest(id, name, summary
                                , location);
                        PointOfInterestLab.get(AppController.getInstance()).addPointOfInterest(pointOfInterest);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

            }

 .....
```